# Optimize slow code that has lots of "for" and "if"

Tags: excel, vba

I have three main sheets: "inputs","variables" and "result". The sheet "inputs" has a list with 150 cells with inputs by the user, the sheet "variable" has a list with more than 30 000 points and "result" is the result of the code.

The code takes a point from the sheet "inputs", searches this point in the "variables" sheet, takes a bunch of information from this sheet an pastes them in the "result" sheet. However the process is really slow, it takes from 7 to 9 minutes to find the 150 inputs. There is any way I can make it faster, or at least half of the time?

The simplified version of the code is shown below, the actual code has at least 5 "for" and 4 "if", due to a lot of conditions presented in the "input" section

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim tag As String
Dim var As String
Dim input As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


Set ws1 = Worksheets("inputs")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("variable")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("result")

For i = 2 To ws2.Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    For j = b To ws2.Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        var = ws2.Cells(j, 4)
        input = ws1.Cells(i, 2), 12, 40)
        If var = specs

           DO STAFF HERE

        End If
    Next j
Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to set calculation mode to manual. Also your `input = ws1.cells...` looks odd to me.

Comment: Also you do a loop over all values, and check if there is a match. It would be faster to use a search function. Also you might benefit from putting your data in arrays first, so as not to interact with the worksheet so much.

Comment: @Luuklag ignore the `, 12, 40)` from the `input=ws1.cells`, is not included in the code. Into arrays? You mean like:
`Dim input As Variant
input= ws1.Range("A:A").Value`

Comment: How do I make the search function?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Comment: Are you even sure you need VBA for this? Is it not possible to do this, using VLookup(), Match(), ... worksheet functions?

Answer (score 0):

You should try saving into an array the looping through said array! always seems to improve efficiency but a loop inside a loop is never great in terms of O(n2) and all that!

```
 Dim varr As Variant
 Dim j as long
 varr = ws2.Range("C1:C" & ws2.Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).value
    For j = LBound(varr) To UBound(varr)
         If varr(j, 1) = specs then
         end if
    Next j
```